# Is there a builtin that I can use to compare a ctype array to a bytearray?

Tags: python, ctypes

let's suppose I have a c code

```
uint8_t testData[] = {0x01U, 0x21U, 0xEFU...};
uint8_t* getData() { return testData;}
```

now lets assume I retrieved the data in python and have a pointer to the data called array1.

At the same time in python I create an array2 = bytearray([0x01,0x21,...])

Is there a builtin that I can use to compare the two arrays?

if not, what would be the cleanest way to do so without having to iterate?

Comment: I guess I found my own answer:
if(True == all(x == y for x, y in zip(array1,array2))):
    print 'It's a match'

Comment: This contains a Python iteration, though.

Comment: [`bytearray_richcompare`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/15c95b7d81dc/Objects/bytearrayobject.c#l1017) uses the buffer protocol to directly compare the buffers using `memcmp`, so the test is simply `array1 == array2`.

Comment: === definitely did not work in this case. may be both arrays would have to be a bytearray type for it to work?

Comment: @Urdar, did you get the result as an array or a pointer? It definitely does work with a ctypes array that's the same size in bytes. OTOH, the buffer of a pointer is just the 4 or 8 bytes for the address. (BTW, notify someone in a comment by prefixing their nick with "@".)